# Парсинг многострочного текст Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Хочу распарсить многострочный текст

```
re.findall(just_text_(\w+)].*another text = (\d+), mytext, re.S)
```

Пример текста

```
[just_text_FIRST_TARGET]
some_text
some_text
another text = 1
some_text
some_text
some_text
some_text
some_text
some_text

[just_text_SECOND_TARGET!]
some_text
some_text
another text = 2
some_text
some_text
some_text
some_text
some_text
some_text
```

Но на выходе не получаю ничего.

Флаги Dotall и Multiline использовал.

На выходе надо получить `[(FIRST_TARGET,1),(SECOND_TARGET,2)]`

Никто с подобным не сталкивался?

Comment: не совсем верно сформулировал - на выходе нужно получить список кортежей всех FIRST_TARGET и 111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все нормально работает:

```
import re

mytext = '''
[just_text_FIRST_TARGET]
some_text
some_text
another text = 111
some_text
some_text
some_text
some_text
some_text
some_text

[just_text_SECOND_TARGET]
some_text
some_text
another text = 112
some_text
some_text
some_text
some_text
some_text
some_text
'''

print(re.findall(r'\[just_text_(\w+)\].*?another text = (\d+)', mytext, re.S))
```

Результат:

```
[('FIRST_TARGET', '111'), ('SECOND_TARGET', '112')]
```

`.*?` дает минимальное совпадение (без вопроса будет результат `[('FIRST_TARGET', '112')]`, т.е. будет взято максимально возможное совпадения для данной строки)

`re.MULTILINE` (он же `re.S`) нужен только если вы хотите чтобы знак `^` матчил начало строки.